# Error: Could not find or load main class org.antlr.v4.Tool Antrl4

Tags: antlr4

I want to use Antlr to create parser and i followed instruction from

[Here](https://levlaz.org/setting-up-antlr4-on-windows/)

after following all instruction while I am running following command 
antlr4 -visitor D:\T\arithmetic.g4
I am getting this error msg:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.antlr.v4.Tool

using this jar file :
C:\Program Files\Java\lib\antlr-4.6-complete.jar

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @TomServo I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your CLASSPATH environment variable isn't set properly.   One [very good tutorial on setting up ANTLR4 is here](http://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial).  This includes instructions for Windows and Unix-based environments.

Comment: I have also used the same link but still not working

Comment: Thanks you were right it is due to CLASSPATH. but somehow I am not able to fix it so instead of setting it permanently I using the command prompt to set it for a specific session using the following command:
SET CLASSPATH=.;D:\g4Files\antlr-4.7-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

Comment: Thanks you were right it is due to CLASSPATH. but somehow I am not able to fix it so instead of setting it permanently I using the command prompt to set it for a specific session using the following command:
SET CLASSPATH=.;D:\g4Files\antlr-4.7-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

Comment: @yashpal There you go.  That is the brute-force approach, but that works too.  Well done!

Comment: I have the same error and I had to solve with the brute-force way. Someone could install instructions from official guide https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md ?

Comment: The tutorial has moved. It's now here : https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/
My problem was different and really dumb. I had set CLASSPATH to the folder containing the jar file, not to jar file itself.

Comment: @jeancallisti Thank you for the updated link!  I've edited the answer to reflect the new location.